# Remove old issues in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have one trouble with Xcode - sometimes errors and warnings in Issue Navigator persists even when they are fixed. So I have no warnings/errors in log. I can run my project, but in status window and in Issues Navigator I see errors.

I can filter them out using "Show only issues from the latest build", but this is not what I want - I want to see all actual warnings.

Do you know how to keep issues up to date?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Older answer was to delete Derived Data, which *can* help. I'd amend this to say delete DD as well as your SPM cache:

`rm -Rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

...and...

`rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm`

---

**Newer Update (2023):** I've found a lot of these that don't go away with Derived Data deletion are down to source files that use symbols from a module the source doesn't import. Xcode seems to get a little confused as to whether an error or warning is actually cleared. Live issues (versus full build) and dependency analysis (of what to rebuild and when) seems to be at play here. If you go through and clean house (and maintain it) with regard to your source files' imports, you may find these go away and stay away.

Comment: Thanks. In XCode 4.5.2 I had to close the project before *Delete* was enabled.

Comment: Xcode 7.3 -- happening too.
Even three major versions later.

Comment: Xcode 9.0.1 as well. I made a copy of a xib/swift pair and accidentally compiled before renaming the files & classes of the copy. The compiler errors got stuck until I cleaned the project, exited Xcode, deleted Derived Data, and reopened Xcode.

Comment: Same with Xcode 9.1. Sigh. Some warnings got stuck when I deleted some files. I quit Xcode, deleted the derived data, and reopened Xcode. All good after that.

Comment: Xcode 12.5.1 and surprise surprise, this issue is still present.

Comment: Still present in Xcode 13, however the Organizer window can't clean derived data anymore. As of now, the only proper way to do that is to quit Xcode and delete the data manually: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: I added a shell alias called “nukedd” for this very purpose.

Comment: Encountering what looks like the same issue in Xcode 11.3 on Catalina. Above steps marked as Solution cannot be performed, there is no Derived Data folder listed in the Xcode UI that I can find. However, @ben's steps below worked to delete the data.

Answer (score 5):

This is still happening in Xcode 9.4.1. The fix is the same as the previous answer for Xcode 6, but the steps are slightly different:

1. Close the project in Xcode
2. Go to Preferences... > Locations
3. Click the arrow next to the Derived Data path, which will open the folder in Finder, e.g. /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
4. Delete the subfolder relevant to the project you're having trouble with
5. Reopen the project

Answer (score 0):

For anyone dealing with this in 2023: Xcode 15 has **Clear All Issues** under the *Product* dropdown.

[image]